# How to use capybara visit without session prefix. getting undefined method `visit' for main:Object (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

Writing a standalone piece of code I can use

```
session.visit('/forms')
```

but how could I use

```
visit('/forms')
```

Code:

```
require 'webdrivers'
require 'rspec'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/rspec'
Capybara.configure do |config|
  config.run_server = false
  config.default_driver = :chrome
  config.app_host = 'https://google.com'
end
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(args: ['window-size=1200,1200'])
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: options)
end

session = Capybara::Session.new(:chrome)
session.visit('/forms') # <-- this works :)
visit('/forms')         # <-- but this doesn't :(
```

I get

```
undefined method `visit' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use include `Capybara::DSL`, i.e.

```
include Capybara::DSL
session = Capybara::Session.new(:chrome)
visit('/forms')
```

However this does give a warning

```
including Capybara::DSL in the global scope is not recommended!
```

not sure how to get around that yet.